# How to current focus edittext in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-intent, android-widget

Hi i want to get edit text which is currently focus at button click , there is any button to doing it .

Or there is a way to identify which edittext is last modified if there are many edit text in activity.

Please suggest me usable link or sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take a linear layout and add custom EditText into it.

```
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        View v = li.inflate(R.layout.addit, null);
        final EditText e = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.e1);
        e.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                System.out.println("--change--");
                mEditText = e;
                System.out.println(e.getText().toString());
            }

        });
        edit_ll.addView(v);
    }
```

Here mEditText is a global variable.

Anywhere in your activity you can access it. And can get what's the last editText you have written into.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a textWatcher to all EditTexts:

```
private class CustomTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private EditText mEditText;

    public CustomTextWatcher(EditText e) {
        mEditText = e;
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
}
```

and can have a global variable to your class to contain editText reference, which is being edited.

Comment: please suggest me how we add your CustomerTextWatcher to edit text final EditText tv= new EditText(getContext());